# Division of large sums; deal with summation up to infinity

Tags: c++, math, floating-point, c++20, division

I'm running an algorithm which generates pairs `(t[i], x[i])`, where both `t[i]` and `x[i]` are positive `double`s. They are not independent; `(t[i], x[i])` depends on `(t[i-1], x[i-1])`. Once the algorithm has finished, I need to divide the sum `a` of all `x[i]` by the sum `b` of all `t[i]`.

It is on purpose that `b` will tend to `infinity` as `i` tends to infinity, since the math behind this computation tells me that in this case `a/b` tends to the value I actually want to compute.

However, this is problematic when I'm trying to implement this algorithm. How can I prevent `b` from actually being equal to infinity at some point? I guess what I would need to do is somehow divide `a` *before* the algorithm has finished by a divider of `b`. For example, if we could write `b = b[1] * b[2]`, then I could divide `a` by `b[1]`, set `b[2]` to zero, sum up further and divide at the end by `b[2]`. However, we once again would need to ensure that `b[2]` doesn't get infinity at some point and there is no easy way for me to know how I should come up with the factorization `b = b[1] * b[2]`.

Another solution might be some kind of "huge floating point" type. I'm open for any recommendation on that, but I need to mention that performance is critical in my application.

Comment: If `b = b[1] * b[2]`, then the natural thing to do is to compute with logarithms: `log(b) = log(b[1]) + log(b[2])`

Comment: There are libraries to handle arbitrary large numbers. Both integers and decimals.

Comment: How fast do your `x` and `t` grow? Are they `O(1)`? `O(i)`? Something in-between? Something greater? What is a typical and maximal value of `i` that you want to support?

Comment: @0xbadf00d "(t[i], x[i]) depends on (t[i-1], x[i-1])" is irrelevant to the problem unless you describe the dependency.  What is the relationship?

Comment: @0xbadf00d, Is the number of elements known before summation begins?

Comment: Can't you simplify the sequence whose limit you intend to calculate? I guess you need more focus on the calculus/math side of the problem, than the programming side. That is, fix the algorithm to avoid infinity in the 1st place.

Comment: Lhopital can be a choice, depending on your problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule?wprov=sfla1

Comment: I wrote an entire python program to do this, even finishing the draft for my answer, before realizing the question was tagged as C++. I am so sad...

Comment: Are you concerned about exceeding the _representable range_ (which is 1.7✕10³⁰⁸, even for a 64-bit `double`; possibly more on your platform's `long-double`)?  Or are you more concerned about _loss of precision_ in the summation, which can be [dealt with more easily](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm)?

Comment: @256Bits, was your Python program significantly better than the standard library [`math.fsum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.fsum)?

Comment: @TobySpeight No. It had some minor advantages, but nothing big.

Comment: Given that (t[i], x[i]) depends on (t[i−1], x[i−1]), then the final result, sum(t[i])/sum(x[i]), is purely a function of the initial value (t[0], x[0]). So is it necessary to compute the summations at all, or can this be solved analytically? Or reduced? Do you want a solution for any arbitrary dependence (x[i], t[i]) = f((x[i−1], t[i−1]) or just a particular f? For an starting values or just particular ones? How many terms do you need? Are t[i] and x[i] integers? How accurate do you need the result to be? Show some examples.

Comment: Can we see the definition of these series, please.

Comment: @EricPostpischil OP did not say that `(t[i], x[i])` depends *only* on `(t[i−1], x[i−1])`. This question clearly needs more details ...

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica the fact that the formulation is recursive might make it a good candidate for Stolz-Cesaro https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem

Answer (score 2):

Adding 2 large values risks overflow to infinity.

So summation must test the magnitude before addition.

Check if either addition operand is near infinity and scale the values as needed.

```
// Pseudo code
power_of_2_max = DBL_MAX_EXP - 1; // Max power of 2 before addition
scale_power_of_2 = 0;
sum = 0.0;
for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
  xi = x[i] / pow(2, scale_power_of_2);
  xi_power_of_2 = get_power_of_2(xi);
  if (xi_power_of_2 > power_of_2_max) {
    xi /= 2;
    sum /= 2;
    scale_power_of_2++;
  }
  sum_power_of_2 = get_power_of_2(sum);
  if (sum_power_of_2 > power_of_2_max) {
    xi /= 2;
    sum /= 2;
    scale_power_of_2++;
  }
  sum += xi;
}

// True sum is sum * pow(2, scale_power_of_2)
```

---

Deeper

Summing many terms leads to imprecision. [@Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76939883/division-of-large-sums-deal-with-summation-up-to-infinity/76940081?noredirect=1#comment135635657_76940081)
If this is important or not depends on unstated OP goals.

Mitigations:

- Use a wider range/more precise floating point type for the summation.
- Sort the values and sum the values least to greatest.

---

Below is *untested* code to better illustrate.  The key is that the sum and `x[i]` are scaled down by powers of 2 which is usually an exact operation and much faster than using `log()`.

Since the scaling for `x[i]` is at least 1 in `sum.d += ldexp(x[i], -sum.expo)` and `sum.d <= DBL_MAX/2`, the addition does not overflow to infinity.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>

static_assert(FLT_RADIX != 10, "TBD code for base 10");

typedef struct {
  double d;
  int expo;
} double_extra_range;

// Return the sum of the array x[] in .d normalized to about 1.0
// with the extended exponent in .expo
// Designed to work with positive numbers.
double_extra_range sum_double(size_t n, const double *x) {
  double_extra_range sum = {.d = 0.0, .expo = 1};
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (sum.d > DBL_MAX / 2) {
      sum.d /= 2;  
      sum.expo++;
    }
    sum.d += ldexp(x[i], -sum.expo);
  }
  // Normalize to about 1.0
  int p;
  sum.d = frexp(sum.d, &p);
  sum.expo += p;
  return sum;
}

double divide_large_sum(size_t n, const double *t, const double *x) {
  double_extra_range t_sum = sum_double(n, t);
  double_extra_range x_sum = sum_double(n, x);
  double quotinet = x_sum.d / t_sum.d;
  return ldexp(quotinet, x_sum.expo - t_sum.expo);
}
```

Comment: `x[i] / pow(2, scale_power_of_2)` is `ldexp(x[i], -scale_power_of_2)`. Large-exponent floating-point can be implemented using `ldexp` and `frexp`. But if OP is concerned sum(`x[i]`) will overflow, then merely extending the exponent may be insufficient, as the sum will lack precision.

Comment: Any particular reason to eschew `long double`?

Comment: @TobySpeight, I suppose OP has already tried that.   Unfortunately `long double` is sometimes the same as `double` or only the 10-byte one and not the generous 16-byte one.  OP has "performance is critical", so `long double`  may not meet that criteria.  AFAIK, its embedded and `long double` incurs a slower throughput.